# How to compile .cls to .r using progress editor 11.6

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a problem. I want to compile manually using the Progress editor in 11.6. But an error occurred. How to compile Class to r-code using the Progress editor in 11.6?

Thank you

Comment: The statement you are using and the error message you get will go a long way to helping us help you. In theory it's just a simple COMPILE statement.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. the error occured when using the COMPILE statement is "could not find class or interface vhpARui.bill_detailUI. (12886)" and "could not compile 'vhpform', which is a super class of 'vhpARui.ar_age1ui. (12918)".  I already defined all propath in the config file. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you've still got a PROPATH issue, or the assemblies are incorrect. Your PROPATH must match in the editor to the PROPATH you use when you compile successfully with other methods. And you need to make sure you have your assemblies set the same too. 
Without knowing your application or environment it will be hard to advise further.

Comment: I've reconstruct the case above and try to add assemblies in Progress Editor 11.6 (Tools > Assembly References) as written in https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvngp/identifying-.net-assemblies-to-abl.html It seems that it still have bugs

Answer (score 1):

Without all the details, the following may be able to work:

```
COMPILE /full/path/to/class/ita_class.cls SAVE INTO /dir/path/where/you/want/it/ .
```

If the comments are on the right track, you may have a problem with your propath. Giving the full path in the COMPILE statement could solve it, but if your class is referencing any other classes or include files, you'll have issues.

You can check what it currently is using `PROPATH`. Each directory in the path is delimited by a comma, and the first place it finds your .cls (or any other file referenced within that file) is what it will use to compile. You can output `PROPATH` to a file or view it like you could any other variable. You can also assign `PROPATH` a new value within a procedure, but it's likely being set in a configuration file somewhere when you initially connect to the database.